# How to move a data block using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a custom tag "quest". I cannot have a table tag inside the "quest" tag. Hence I need jQuery to render the table at the correct position. Currently the html is written as below:

```
<pre><code>
<li><table block_type="no_border_table">
    <tbody>
    <tr><th></th><th>Lemons</th></tr>
    <tr><td>White</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Green</td></tr>
    <tr><td>OMEGA</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Happiness</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <quest>Consider Table 1. For lemons
    How do we change this?
    a. Grapes
    b. Apples
    c. Mangoes
    d. Towels
    </quest>
    </li>
</code></pre>
```

When rendering, I need the table between the sentence text and the multiple choice like this:

```
<pre><code>
<li>
    <quest>Consider Table 1. For lemons
    How do we change this?
    <table block_type="no_border_table">
    <tbody>
    <tr><th></th><th>Lemons</th></tr>
    <tr><td>White</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Green</td></tr>
    <tr><td>OMEGA</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Happiness</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
    a. Grapes
    b. Apples
    c. Mangoes
    d. Towels
    </quest>
    </li>
</code></pre>
```

I have seen examples of append(), prepend(), etc at http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-removing-replacing-moving-elements/ However, I am not sure how to move the table between two text bodies. I am new to jQuery, hence would appreciate a very detailed answer.

thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) - such as [descendant](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and first/nth child

Comment: `code` cannot have `li` as a child

Answer (score 0):

Use Span

```
<pre><code>   
<li><table id="table" block_type="no_border_table">
<tbody>
<tr><th></th><th>Lemons</th></tr>
<tr><td>White</td></tr>
<tr><td>Green</td></tr>
<tr><td>OMEGA</td></tr>
<tr><td>Happiness</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<quest>
<span id="tab">Consider Table 1. For lemons
How do we change this?</span>
<span id="tag">
a. Grapes
b. Apples
c. Mangoes
d. Towels
</span>
</quest>
</li>
</code></pre>
```

while rendering use

// tab-content of above message

```
var text=$("#tab").html();
$("#table").before(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var q = $("quest").html();
q = q.replace(/\./g,"specialchar");
$("quest").remove();
$("li").wrap("<quest>"+q+"</quest>");
q = $("quest").html();
q = q.replace(/specialchar/g,".");
$("quest").html(q);
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ty9S2/)